# Call customized gem from console

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I downloaded the code of em-ftpd and made some necessary changes to it locally. I don't want to fork It, just use the changes I made.
Also, I have other project that implements a new driver for this ftp server.
In the driver's folder I need to call em-ftpd gem, but with my own modified code.
It would be nice if can be done with bundler.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bundler you can reference a gem in the file system:

```
gem 'em-ftpd', :path => 'path/to/your/gem'
```

Comment: It seems to work but gives the following error: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find em-ftpd (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-3.2.8, actionpack-3.2.8, 
activemodel-3.2.8, activerecord-3.2.8, activeresource-3.2.8, activesupport-3.2.8, arel-3.0.2, aws-s3-0.6.3, builder-3.1.3, builder-3.0.3, bundler-1.2.1, diff-lcs-1.1.3, em-redis-0.3.
0, erubis-2.7.0, eventmachine-1.0.0, ffi-1.0.11, guard-1.3.3, guard-bundler-1.0.0, guard-process-1.0.3 ...

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after changing the Gemfile?

Comment: Yes, i ran bundle install on the custom gem folder, and in my driver folder, no errors shown.

Comment: Custom gem works when using gem install em-ftpd inside the custom gem's folder. But when I try to use bundler install with :path => 'path_to_custom_gem', em-ftpd command gives the error I commented.

Comment: Working using bundle exec em-ftpd, that calls my custom implementation on the folder I specified with no errors.